# Distance from a point to origin of a discrete dynamical system with complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm given the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -3 \\ 3 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. This has eigenvalues $3 \pm3i$ with eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \pm i\end{bmatrix}$. For another part of the problem I find that $$A = r \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix} = \sqrt{18} \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\pi/4) & -\sin(\pi/4) \\ \sin(\pi/4) & \cos(\pi/4) \end{bmatrix}$$
So this scales a vector by $\sqrt{18}$ and rotates it by $\pi/4$ radians.
Then I do some iterations of the system $x_{k+1} = Ax_k$ starting with $x_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Next I must find a formula for the distance from $x_k$ to the origin. I started individually calculating the distances for $x_0$ $x_1$ and $x_2$, which were $1$, $\sqrt{18}$, and $\sqrt{235}$ respectively. Clearly this has something to do with $r$ that I calculated earlier but I don't know how to find it. This isn't in the textbook but I've tried to reason it from the knowledge I have so far about complex eigenvalues. I know the trajectory of the system is spiraling out from the origin.

How can I find a formula for the distance of any $x_k$ from the origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your computation you have obtained that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}A$ is an orthogonal matrix, so that

$$|| x_{k+1}||=|| Ax_k||=||\sqrt{18}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}\cdot Ax_k||=\sqrt{18}||x_k||=\dots =\sqrt{18}^{k+1}||\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} ||=\sqrt{18}^{k+1}=3^{k+1}\sqrt{2}^{k+1}.$$

Therefore $||x_k||=3^{k}\sqrt{2}^{k}.$

Observe that for instance $||x_2||=18$ and not $\sqrt{235}$, so maybe you did some mistakes.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was r^k but when it didn't match ||x_2|| I was confused. it seems last night I was just calculating that wrong, that clears it up.

Comment: You're welcome :D